# Postgresql Regexp_replace group

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

Sorry my english

i have this query

```
select regexp_replace('Hello OBLIG: 451451, world OBLIG: 12123456789, Task OBLIG: 789456123, world ', '(OBLIG: )([^,]*)', '\1\2' , 'g')
```

I need to return something like this

```
Hello OBLIG: 1451, world OBLIG: 6789, Task OBLIG: 6123, world
```

the number after "OBLIG:" should be the last 4 digits

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
select regexp_replace(
    'Hello OBLIG: 451451, world OBLIG: 12123456789, Task OBLIG: 789456123, world ', 
    '(OBLIG: )([[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]{4})', '\1\3' ,
    'g'
);
```

Of course, this assumes you *always* have at least 4 digits in each number.